# Filter emails by date using hours and minutes 

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I'm trying to get all mail that I receive after some date. But `folder.search(` returns all of them. Even if I specify `ComparisonTerm.EQ`

```
Folder folder = getInboxFolder();
ReceivedDateTerm dateTerm = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ, new Date());
Message[] messages = folder.search(dateTerm);
```

How I should correct my code?

**UPD** It seems that it make job right with year/month/day comparation, but what about hours and minutes?  I should care about them too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650592/javamail-how-to-get-new-messages-comparing-with-time-stamps

Comment: Voted to close as duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally looks like it's not possible to do so. check this thread: [Click here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650592/javamail-how-to-get-new-messages-comparing-with-time-stamps)